# Does writing to a file with no seeks flush bytes sequentially on all file systems?

Tags: filesystems

I'm writing JSON files. This means that for each `'{'` character, there is a corresponding `'}'` and the last byte in the file is `'}'`. The writes happen sequentially. There are no fseeks. Thus if the write to the file is somehow interrupted, I expect to have an invalid JSON file.

Now a hypothetical file system might decide to flush my bytes out of order. This would mean that if a power outage happens during writing, before everything is flushed, I could get a valid JSON which does not contain the data I intended. I could have the string `"xxx"`, instead of `"yyy"`, or missing digits from the end of numbers.

Does such a file system exist? Can I rely on the fact that if a file is valid, then it's guaranteed to be complete?

Edit: This question is for the case where the data cannot be valid if it's missing its last byte. JSON is illustrative here. Techincally `42342` is a valid JSON, which cannot be validated if incomplete.

Comment: Are you overwriting existing files, or writing new files? Which file system are you using?

Comment: I'm writing new files. Also I develop and test the software on ntfs and ext4, but it's intended for a library which could potentially run on any file system

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several reasons why the filesystem may flush your pages out of order:

- The page has data from 2 files, and the other file is being flushed to disk.
- The page is outside of the process' working set (and therefore not worth caching) and the OS needs the memory for other purposes.
- The filesystem is distributed e.g. OrangeFS or Andrew Filesystem, and plays by very different implementation rules.
- The filesystem NFS fronting a more complex distributed, heterogeneous set of devices where some writes are fully synchronous and the application is none the wiser.

And it's not just the filesystem, but also the underlying device.

- The block device may do buffering until the filesystem actually requires a full flush, and flushes it in whatever order it sees proper (since it's unaware of the concept of files).
- The block device could be striped (RAID 0), so that one device may flush before the other.

That said, it's very unlikely to experience a loss of 3 bytes like `xxx` after a crash. It's more likely to experience loss of blocks, e.g. of multiples of 4096 bytes.

Truth is, most filesystems make little to no guarantees about integrity of data written during a crash (as opposed to metadata).

When atomicity is required, what applications typically do is leverage [`rename(2)`](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Renaming-Files.html#Renaming-Files) or its equivalents:

1. Write to a temporary file e.g. with [POSIX `write(2)`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/write.html#tag_16_685).
2. Flush the file e.g. with [POSIX `fsync(2)`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fsync.html) and close it.
3. Rename the file to the target name, e.g. with [POSIX `rename(2)`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/rename.html).

All the POSIX filesystems I know that are in active use implement POSIX rename in a crash-safe manner, I assume NTFS does as well.

But it's apparently not strictly required by POSIX. Since you're writing new files, this is less of a problem, but if you want to be extra paranoid, you could add another step:

4. Delete the temporary file (ignore the error if it doesn't exist).